# Import with Babel and Webpack loader in Vue.js

Tags: webpack, vue.js, babel-loader

I cannot get past this linting error. I feel like I'm tried everything. Can someone help me out?

```
ERROR in ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Register.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/services/AuthenticationService' in 'C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\tabtracker\tabtracker\client\src\components'
 @ ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Register.vue 25:0-69
 @ ./src/components/Register.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
```

So basically I searched through the web looking for an answer and it seems to be a common enough problem. I checked out the same issue on the [official vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-loader-unexpected-token-error-for-using-spread-operator-on-my-vue-component/10241/7) and was not able to have a successful build. I read through github issues like crazy and still feel no closer.

I've tried rolling babel back and adding a plugin but i'm afraid I'm not adding them to the correct config files, there's so many.

Webpack base config file::

```
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    },
    symlinks: false
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
        options: {
          formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": ["istanbul"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your webpack config file

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the plugins you've installed, more like a config/path issue, please post your webpack config file

Comment: I posted the webpack config file, thanks! I'm trying to add more options to the view loader because it doesn't seem to want to complie regular js files

Comment: import AuthenticationService from '/services/AuthenticationService'  this is how i'm importing the necessary file in my component

Comment: you need to import like so  
`import AuthenticationService from './services/AuthenticationService'`

Comment: @AmrAly it's not about the import, it has to do with however babel isn't pulling in a js file through the loader. This returns the same error because the code hasn't been complied. At least that's what I think. Either way, I appreciate the help. I might have to abandon this project and start over if I can't get past this

Comment: Maybe could my dependencies be out of sync?     "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",

Comment: @AmrAly I've added the babrc file. It looks like I need to make a change there based off your recommendation. Would you be able to tell me how I should add your change into the file? It's not clear to me

Comment: this is the minimum configuration for .babelrc if you already have .babelrc don't change it